# Datatables problem's on render data into input

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am currently maintenance on some project using Datatables:

I found a problem when export the column that is successfully displayed on page failed to display after use render as below :

```js
this._dataTable = this.$mainTable.DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: this.url,
    dataSrc: ''
  },
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  fixedColumns: {
    leftColumns: 3,
    rightColumns: 1
  },
  orderable: false,
  rowId: 'fsId',
  scrollX: true,
  scrollCollapse: true,
  columns: [{
      className: 'input-cell',
      data: 'stadate',
      render(data) {
        const time = data ? moment(data).format('HH:mm DD-MM-YYYY') : '';

        return time;
      },
      width: '100px'
    },

    {
      className: 'input-cell',
      data: 'slotTime',
      render(data) {
        const time = data ? moment(data).format('HH:mm') : '';

        return `<input name="slotTime" class="form-control" data-time value="${time}" size="5" readonly>`;
      },
      width: '72px'
    },
  ],
  buttons: [{
    extend: 'print',
    customize: function(win) {
      $(win.document.body).find('table')
        .addClass('compact')
        .css('font-size', 'inherit');
    }
  }]
});
```

Data in column `stadate` can be displayed successfully, both on webpage and export page, but data `slotTime` successfully displays on webpage only.

Appreciate for any solution to fix it.. regards

Comment: Change `value="${time}"` to `...value="'+time+'"...`. ${} should not be used for js

Comment: thx for your suggestion @samabcde, however I just found solution from here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52956031/datatables-export-values-inside-and-outside-the-field-input-and-value-of-the-s) by adding in button 'exportOptions: {
                        orthogonal: 'export',
                    }' and coloumn 'render: function (data, type, row) {
            return type === 'export' ? row.Descripcion: "";
        }'

Answer (score 0):

finally, I can found sollution from here [Datatables - Export values inside and outside the field input and value of the select field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52956031/datatables-export-values-inside-and-outside-the-field-input-and-value-of-the-s) and here my final code :

```
this._dataTable = this.$mainTable.DataTable({
```

ajax: {
    url: this.url,
    dataSrc: ''
  },
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  fixedColumns: {
    leftColumns: 3,
    rightColumns: 1
  },
  orderable: false,
  rowId: 'fsId',
  scrollX: true,
  scrollCollapse: true,
  columns: [{
      className: 'input-cell',
      data: 'stadate',
      render(data) {
        const time = data ? moment(data).format('HH:mm DD-MM-YYYY') : '';

```
    return time;
  },
  width: '100px'
},

{
  className: 'input-cell',
  data: 'slotTime',
  render: function (data, type, row) {
const time = data ? moment(data).format('HH:mm') : '';

return type === 'export' ? time : `<input name="slotTime" class="form-control" data-time value="${time}" size="5" readonly>`;
  },
  width: '72px'
},
```

],
  buttons: [{
    extend: 'print',
    exportOptions : {
    orthogonal: 'export',
    },

}]
});

thx all